# Le compré un regalo para Pedro

Tags: pronombres, preposiciones, objetos-indirectos

Is the following sentence correct?

> Le compré un regalo para Pedro.

Does it mean the following?

> I bought (from him/her) a present for Pedro.

I ask because a friend gave me the following example sentence:

> Le compré a Juan un regalo para Pedro.

and I am trying to replace "a Juan" with a pronoun, if that is allowed.

Comment: The English you are trying to use should be: I bought a present for Pedro from him. Your friend is right. You can't replace a Juan because then you'd get: Le compré a Juan un regalo de él.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

- Le compré a Juan un regalo para Pedro.

"le" is a double indirect object that has the same referent as "a Juan." If it is clear from the context that you are referring to Juan, you can omit it and "le" will be the only indirect object:

- Le compré un regalo para Pedro.

If the direct object is replaced by "lo", then "le" will become "se":

- Se lo compré para Pedro. (Here, "se" refers to Juan.)

Comment: We don't say double indirect object. The le and a Juan refer to the same person. Le compré a ella, a él, a Juan. That is the Spanish need to identify who the le refers to. And you have not omitted the le, you omitted the Juan.

Comment: We call it "duplicación del complemento indirecto" (the result of duplication is a double indirect object). You can read it here: https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos

Comment: Duplicación de complementos: coaparición del clítico y el complemento tónico. En español, los pronombres átonos aparecen a menudo dentro de la misma oración junto con el complemento tónico al que se refieren: Me dijo a mí que me callara; Lo sabe todo.  We would not call that duplication. In English, You can describe that as "doubling" the pronoun. Not duplicating. That's a false friend here. duplicar has two meanings in Spanish and only one is duplicate, the other is double something.

Comment: That's why I said: DOUBLE indirect object in English (one is pronominal, the other is nominal, with both of them having the same referent) and used DUPLICACIÓN in Spanish. If you take the trouble to read the whole article, you will find the following examples: A mi madre le he dicho la verdad (no *A mi madre he dicho la verdad); A Juan le han denegado la beca (no *A Juan han denegado la beca); Le molestó a tu padre que no vinieras; Le ha cansado a la abuela el paseo; Le pareció bien al jefe nuestro plan; No le conviene al niño comer tantos dulces.

Comment: Look, you said: "(the result of duplication is a double indirect object)" **should be**: the result of doubling the indirect object. With regard to English, just believe me. Also, we say reflexive verbs in English. Why don't you just acknowledge you said it? I don't know as much about Spanish as you, obviously. And you don't know as much about English. A little humility is in order.

Comment: Only now do I see what you mean. You are right. I should have said, "the result of "duplicación" is a double indirect object". (As for being humble, and polite, you could perhaps do some introspection.)

Comment: Gustavson, the result of doubling, ing the indirect object. :) My annoyance is only when people who are clueless say things that are completely wrong (not your case of course). I am the first person to recognize her own limitations. Unlike others on many sites on SE.